# Why should QR decomposition not be possible for a "fat" matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) on QR decomposition states:

> More generally, we can factor a complex m×n matrix A, with m ≥ n, as the product of an m×m unitary matrix Q and an m×n upper triangular matrix R.

I was just wondering what would happen if I tried to QR decompose a matrix with more columns than rows. I'd just follow Gram-Schmidt (described in the same [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition)) until I got an $m \times m$ orthonormal matrix. Then, the remaining columns of $R$, (given the original one's were $c_j$) would just become $Q^{-1}c_j$.

Comment: You can use the RQ decomposition

Comment: Q^Tc_{j) correct?

Comment: Right, which is the same as transposing and doing a QR. I'm just wondering if we can say that the Wikipedia sentence is incorrect.

Comment: @RileyCarney - same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I'm convinced now that the only reason they require $m>n$ is for semantic purposes, not wanting to call the resulting $R$ matrix "upper triangular". Because one could always take just the square part of a "fat" matrix, QR decompose it and then multiply the remaining columns by $Q^{-1}$ from the right. We would get something like the picture below.

[image]